# Customize soap body in Ksoap2 (Android)

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I'm trying to call a web service thru Ksoap 2.5 now. My question is if there is anyway to customize soap xml body?

Right now ksoap generates the following code snippet:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <v:Header/>
  <v:Body>
    <n0:TVerifyCode xmlns:n0="urn:AccessDBIntf-IAccessDB" id="o0" c:root="1">
      <UserId i:type="d:string">bfy</UserId>
      <PassWord i:type="d:string">351F42CE0189FAD45AF2EA252A1F149A</PassWord>      
    </n0:TVerifyCode>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

And the web service server complains that "The soap message you provided is invalid."

If I change the snippet in the following way, the code will work:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:NS1="urn:AccessDBIntf-IAccessDB" xmlns:NS2="urn:CommonObj" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <NS1:Login>
      <VerifyCode href="#1"/>
    </NS1:Login>
    <NS2:TVerifyCode id="1" xsi:type="NS2:TVerifyCode">
      <UserId xsi:type="xsd:string">bfy</UserId>
      <PassWord xsi:type="xsd:string">F0639A434D0A852488F45A3071E009A6</PassWord>      
    </NS2:TVerifyCode>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any ideas to customize the envelope body? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating your own soap request.

https://github.com/Abhan/SoapWithoutKSoap

Please refer to above library,this guy has created soap request without any soap library. Its pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the result I wanted。